# Semantic Similarity in Python for matching composite words

Tags: python-2.7

I need help in finding a semantic similarity measure to find matching composite terms.

For example, cereal crop and cereals are matching terms, we have many semantic similarity measures like WUP and LI which find semantic matches between words, but the problem is the underlying dictionary that they use does not support composite terms, that's why these measures do not work with the composite terms. Word2Vec also works on single word terms. Please suggest some method to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the semantic similarity between multi-words or phrases (I guess this is what you meant by **composite terms**), you need to convert word vectors to phrase vectors.

Here is a step by step tutorial: [How to calculate phrase similarity between phrases](https://bitbucket.org/yunazzang/aiwiththebest_byor)